# What is the relationship between $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ and $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry, holonomy, geometric-structures

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\R{\mathbb{R}}$The holonomy of a hyperbolic surface $S$ in terms of differential geometry is either $\SO(2)$ or $\mathrm{O}(2)$ depending on orientability or a hyperbolic structure as a special $(X,G)$-structure $\pi_1(S)\subset \PSL(2,\R)$. (An $(X,G)$-structure could be regarded as a flat $X$-bundle with a section transversal to the flat connection, so holonomy of the flat bundle is the holonomy of the structure.)

So there are two ways of describing the holonomy of a hyperbolic structure. But, are they both equally as valid? And what is the relationship between $\SO(2)$ and $\PSL(2,\R)$?

Comment: $SO(2)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $PSL(2,R)$.

Comment: What do you mean by two ways? Do you mean two possible groups: $S0(2)$ or $O(2)$? What do you mean by  "equally as valid"? Surely both possibilities occur on different hyperbolic surfaces, but only one or the other on a given hyperbolic surface.

Comment: Well if there an orientability condition, then O(n) has a reduction to SO(n), so its either SO(n) or O(n) depending on if the space is orientable. And equally valid refers to the idea that in differential geometry, you would use either SO(n) and O(n) (depending on Orientability) or in terms of hyperbolic geometry you would use a special $(X,G)$ structure $\pi_1(S)  ⊂ PSL(2,R)$. I wanted to know if there was a difference in outcome based on the method used.

Comment: Also, can you let me know what subgroup of $PSL(2,R)$ $SO(2)$ is isomorphic to?

Comment: @BurakGuner Do you know how to embed SO(2) in SL(2,R)? If you do, then take the quotient by the center to get to PSL(2,R). Or think of the unit disk model of the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391593/what-is-the-relationship-between-mathrmso2-and-mathrmpsl2-mathbbr#comment998683_391593), the embedding of $\operatorname{SO}(2, \mathbb R)$ in $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ that I know induces an embedding of $\operatorname{SO}(2, \mathbb R)/\langle\pm1\rangle$, not of $\operatorname{SO}(2, \mathbb R)$ itself, into $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)/\langle\pm1\rangle$.  Do you have another embedding in mind?

Comment: @LSpice: They are isomorphic!

Comment: [Cross-posted at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122508/what-is-the-relationship-between-s02-and-psl2-r) (where this question truly belongs).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yea, sorry about that. I tried asking MSE, but got no responses so I tried my luck here instead. Also, thank you everyone for the help =) it really means a lot.

Comment: You did not get an immediate response, of course, but Igor Rivin did post one within an hour (although, his response is characteristically terse). The right way to approach this is to wait for a few days and if no satisfactory response is given, then post at MO and add notes on cross-posting in order to avoid duplication of efforts. Please, do so in the future.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ok, thank you for the information, I will make sure to follow those guidelines from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider  $Q(x_0,x_1,x_2)=x_0^2-x_1^2-x_2^2$, and $H=\{(x_0,x_1,x_2):x_0>0,Q(x_1,x_2,x_3)=1$.

The restriction of $B(x,y)={1\over 2}(Q(x+v)-Q(v))$ to the tangent space of elements of $H$ defines on $H$ a Riemannian metric whose curvature is $-1$. Its group of isometries is the restriction of $O(1,n)$ to $H$.

A (complete) closed Hyperbolic surface $S$ is the quotient of $H$ by a subgroup of isometries $h:\pi_1(S)\rightarrow O(1,n)$, and the holonomy of this structure is defined $h$ ( the holonomy  of the flat bundle defined by $h$ over $S$). If the surface is oriented, the image of $h$ is contained in $SO^+(1,n)$ which is isomorphic to $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

There is a natural local diffeomorphism $H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ defined by $D(x)=[x]$ where $[x]$ is the projective line throught $x$. $D(x)$ is the developing map of the projective structure defined on $S$ the quotient of $H$ by $\pi_1(S)$.